# FVM shortcut is not showing in android studio and not showing code suggestion for flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, fvm

I have used fvm stable in terminal, but it still doesn't show the code suggestion
with both CTRL+SPACE and other combinations key. also when i started typing it didn't show the code suggestion.

[flutter_sdk is not showing(please click here to see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M36SK.png)

i cannot see the flutter_sdk shortcut in the .fvm folder inside of my project.

I have tried reinstalling android studio, fvm and chocolatey too.
none of them are working.

Here is my stable version -

Flutter 3.16.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision db7ef5bf9f (2 weeks ago) • 2023-11-15 11:25:44 -0800
Engine • revision 74d16627b9
Tools • Dart 3.2.0 • DevTools 2.28.2

fvm version - 2.4.1

flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):

[!] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.16.0, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22631.2715], locale en-IN)
! Warning: `dart` on your path resolves to C:\tools\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe, which is not inside your current Flutter SDK checkout at C:\Users\Magesh\fvm\versions\stable. Consider adding
C:\Users\Magesh\fvm\versions\stable\bin to the front of your path.

[✓] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.84.2)

[✓] Connected device (2 available)

[✓] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.